# why i got an error when i import winshell module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, python-winshell, win32con

here is my code:

```
import os

try:
    import winshell
except:
    os.system('python -m pip  install --upgrade pip')
    os.system('pip install pywin32')
    os.system('pip install winshell')
    import winshell

print('hello world')
```

i want to import winshell module,and when it didn't install,install it and then import it again.

but i got an error

```
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\mini\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (18.1)
Collecting pywin32
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8a/37/917c4020e93e0e854d4cbff1cbdf14ec45a6d1cedf52f8cafdea5b22451a/pywin32-224-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
Installing collected packages: pywin32
Successfully installed pywin32-224
Collecting winshell
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/91/3f/d23d248029a49042d278af9c86b53bc90845e3739a0d7493e00cbac0e4cd/winshell-0.6.zip
Installing collected packages: winshell
  Running setup.py install for winshell: started
    Running setup.py install for winshell: finished with status 'done'
Successfully installed winshell-0.6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\share\test.py", line 4, in <module>
    import winshell
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'winshell'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\share\test.py", line 9, in <module>
    import winshell
  File "C:\Users\mini\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\winshell.py", line 30, in <module>
    import win32con
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32con'
[Finished in 13.6s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "D:\share\test.py"]
[dir: D:\share]
[path: C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\mini\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\mini\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\]
```

the script installed the pywin32 and winshell,but then,it said that no module named winshell,and i have to try this script again.

and i tried another module

```
import os

try:
    import requests
except:
    os.system('python -m pip  install --upgrade pip')
    os.system('pip install requests')
    import requests

print('hello world')
```

it works well

```
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\mini\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (18.1)
Collecting requests
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/65/47/7e02164a2a3db50ed6d8a6ab1d6d60b69c4c3fdf57a284257925dfc12bda/requests-2.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (91kB)
Collecting urllib3<1.24,>=1.21.1 (from requests)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bd/c9/6fdd990019071a4a32a5e7cb78a1d92c53851ef4f56f62a3486e6a7d8ffb/urllib3-1.23-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133kB)
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a9/01ffebfb562e4274b6487b4bb1ddec7ca55ec7510b22e4c51f14098443b8/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133kB)
Collecting idna<2.8,>=2.5 (from requests)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4b/2a/0276479a4b3caeb8a8c1af2f8e4355746a97fab05a372e4a2c6a6b876165/idna-2.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58kB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/df/f7/04fee6ac349e915b82171f8e23cee63644d83663b34c539f7a09aed18f9e/certifi-2018.8.24-py2.py3-none-any.whl (147kB)
Installing collected packages: urllib3, chardet, idna, certifi, requests
Successfully installed certifi-2018.8.24 chardet-3.0.4 idna-2.7 requests-2.19.1 urllib3-1.23
hello world
[Finished in 10.5s]
```

then i got confused,why the first script need to run twice but the second one only need just once?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille thank you for remainding me ,i have editted again

Comment: Can you check if your py env has `win32con` module installed. The trace ends with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32con'` . Check this

Comment: @ShivkumarBirnale yes,i have checked,after i ran the script,and check the pip list,pywin32 and winshell have installed successfully